# How to connect to custom UIViewContoller with xib on Storybord

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I created MyViewController.swift and MyViewController.xib files.
Then I put label on xib file.

I droped to UIViewController on the Storyboad.
Then I changed it's 'Custom Class' UIViewController to MyViewController.

But it does not appear the label which on xib.

How can I show the MyViewController with xib?
Should I write some code in MyViewController to relate with xib?

I just want to reuse components with xib in my app.

Comment: Your best bet is to recreate the MyViewController UI in the storyboard and eliminate the xib. I doubt you can reuse the xib with the storyboard involved.

Answer (score 0):

Your MyViewController.swift file should at least contain the declaration for the class as this :
    import UIKit

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

inside your class declaration you will also need the following if you want to load your view from the xib :

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    // Custom initialization
}
```

Finally in order to access your label you can create an IBOutlet in your class declaration like this:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel?
```

Then you will be able to connect it using Interface Builder and access it in your code